# angular2- Observable getting data from list out of order

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

```
    for (let i = 0; i < this.data.VirtualHosts.length; i++) {
                // get the vh
                this.apiService.findVH(this.data.VirtualHosts[i])
                    // then add each vhost to data by concat and then convert to json
                    .subscribe((data) => {
                        this.data = data.docs[0]
                        this.jsonData = this.jsonData.concat(this.data)
                        //console.log("AFTER: " + this.jsonData[i]._id)
                        //console.log("Response for getVH: " + JSON.stringify(this.jsonData))

                    })
            }
```

Here, I loop through a list of ID's of VirtualHosts and do a get call (findVH) on every single one of them. However, the get call seems to be calling each index out of order. How would I make it so that the get call returns a list of data in the order that it was given in the this.data.VirtualHosts list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to do 2 things.  One convert your this.data.VirtualHosts into an observable using the from operator as described here:

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/from.md

Then use concatMap which will force the api results to return in the order that you are firing off the requests.  This is explained here:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html

Comment: Yep, I followed what you said and it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend to use an observable inside a loop unless you really have to.. consider get all of your data within one api call / observable. If you are not unsubscribing from each one of the observables you will end up with a memory leak (unless you are using angular http).

Anyway, try wrap your code with a timeout to add it to the event queue:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.data.VirtualHosts.length; i++) {
setTimeout(() => { 
                // get the vh
                this.apiService.findVH(this.data.VirtualHosts[i])
                    // then add each vhost to data by concat and then convert to json
                    .subscribe((data) => {
                        this.data = data.docs[0]
                        this.jsonData = this.jsonData.concat(this.data)
                        //console.log("AFTER: " + this.jsonData[i]._id)
                        //console.log("Response for getVH: " + JSON.stringify(this.jsonData))

                    })
}, 0);
            }
```

Currently the for loop ends before your service method is being exeucuted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using this code gives me an error and states that property of this.apiService.findVH is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The return values are in an incorrect order mainly due to the fact that `Observables` will create a separate thread per call therefore the loop completes before the result arrives; this is why unordered list. What I done in this kind of situation is to put that in a method, store the unordered list and then filter the result to another variable by running a something like `find` or `filter` method to use common value from `this.data.virtualHosts` and the unordered result to put them back to order.