# Getting observable values in order when looping?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular2-services

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to print users in order using Observables.  Right now this will print out of order depending on when the requests are resolved.  How do I get it to print in order?

```
printUsersInOrder() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    this.getUser(i)
  }
}

// kibanaService uses angular2/http
getUser(userId: int) {
  this.kibanaService.getUser(userId).subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(userId)
      console.log(res)
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: This page talks about same issue. please check this.
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974036/angular2-observable-getting-data-from-list-out-of-order">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974036/angular2-observable-getting-data-from-list-out-of-order</a>

Comment: You should take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798178/angular4-httpclient-many-requests-in-succession/45798433#45798433

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular4: HttpClient - many requests in succession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798178/angular4-httpclient-many-requests-in-succession)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `combineLatest` RxJs stream.

```
  printUsersInOrder() {
    let requests = [];
    let successfulResponses = []; // <-- Let's keep track of successful responses
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      requests.push(this.getUser(i).do(res => successfulResponses.push(res)))
    }

    Observable.combineLatest(requests)
    .subscribe((responses)=>{
        // response array will have the same order as it is in the requests array
        responses.map(res => console.log(res))
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(successfulResponses) // <--- This will print all successful responses
        console.log(err)
    })
  }

  // kibanaService uses angular2/http
  getUser(userId: int) {
    this.kibanaService.getUser(userId)
  }
```

For more about `combineLatest` you can find [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) and [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest).

Comment: Do you know how to catch exceptions?  Whenever an error is hit, combineLatest bails.

Comment: Where the line: `console.log(err)` written. There you can catch the errors. If one of the requests failed the error callback will be called.

Comment: If 4/5 of the request work - I still want the results from the 4 that worked.  Right now if 4 work and 1 failed, I lose all the results.  Any idea what to do?

Comment: @sunflowerprincess I've updated my answer. Hope it will help.